# Mechanize POSTing error

Tags: php, perl, post, get, mechanize

Alright, been many long hours pouring over this script to get it up and running, now the only problem I'm running into are occasional GET and POST errors that cause it to restart the script, which is quite annoying .

```
sub Fight {
my($cpm);
$parsed = 0; while ($parsed == 0) {sleep(3);
$mech->get("http://www.lordsoflords.com/m3/fight_control.php");
$a = $mech->content();if ($a =~ m/Skeleton/) {$parsed = 1;}}
$mech->form_number(2);
$mech->field("Difficulty", $level);
$mech->click();
$cpm = $mech->content();
$cpm =~ m/(\<option\>208.*Duke)/;
$cpm = $1;
$cpm =~ s/ - Shadowlord Duke//g;
$cpm =~ s/\>209/\>/;
$cpm =~ s/<.*?>//g;
if($debug == 1) {
    print $cpm . "\n";
}
$mech->form_number(1);
$mech->select("Monster", $cpm);
$mech->click();
$a = $mech->content();
$a =~ m/(You win.*exp )/;
$a =~ m/(battle)/;
$a =~ m/(You have been jailed for violating our rules)/;
print $1 . "\n";
my $antal = 500 + int rand (500);
my $antal = 5000;
my $jail;

# REPEAT:
while($antal > 0) {
    sleep($loopwait); #default = 0.3
    $antal = $antal -1;
    $mech->reload();
    $a = $mech->content();
    $b = $a;
    $c = $a;
```

One line I'm getting the error on is the $mech->reload() command in the repeat section which is returning an error that looks like this: "Error POSTing http://www.lordsoflords.com/m3/fight.php: Bad Request at booyaka.pl line 299".

Also sometimes return this error "Error GETing http://www.lordsoflords.com/m3/steal.php: Can't connect to www.lordsoflords.com:80 (Bad hostname) at booyaka.pl line 97".

The function this is attached to is the following:

```
sub Stealwait {
    $stealwait = 3600;
    $stealtime = time;
    $stealtime = $stealtime + $stealwait; # if stealer can't be found, click for 1k seconds
    print time . "|" . $stealtime . "\n";
    print "stealtime: " . $stealtime . "\n";
    $parsed = 0; $stealcount = 0;
    while ($parsed == 0) {sleep(3);
    print $stealcount . "\n";
    $mech->get("http://www.lordsoflords.com/m3/steal.php");
    $a = $mech->content();
    if ($a =~ m/Parsed/) {$parsed = 1; $stealwait = 0;}
    $stealcount = $stealcount+1; if ($stealcount == 5) {
    }
if ($a =~ m/recover/)
{
    $a = $mech->content();
    $a =~ m/(Take.*This)/s;
    $b = $1;
    $b =~ s/<.*?>//sg;
    $b =~ m/(Take.*seconds)/s;
    $b = $1;
     print $b . "\n";
    $b =~ m/(for.*seconds)/s;
    $b = $1;
    $b =~ s/for//sg;
    $b =~ s/seconds//sg;
    $b =~ s/<.*?>//sg;
    $b =~ s/,//g;
            $b = 2*$b;
            $stealwait = $b;
            print "In recover, gotta wait " . $stealwait . " seconds before I can steal...\n";
            $stealtime = time;
            $stealtime = $stealtime + $stealwait;
    }


    sub Steal {
$parsed = 0; while ($parsed == 0) {sleep(3);
$mech->get("http://www.lordsoflords.com/m3/steal.php");
$a = $mech->content();if ($a =~ m/Parsed/) {$parsed = 1;}}
    $a = $mech->content();
    if ($a =~ m/Freeplay/) { # steal only if we have freeplay
            $a = "\<option\>" . "$stealchar" . ".*?\<\/option\>";
            $tmp = $mech->content();
            #print $tmp;
            if($tmp =~ m/($a)/) {print "Stealer found\n";} else {print "Stealer not found! - not stealing!\n"; return();}
            $tmp =~ m/($a)/s;
            $tmp = $1;
            $tmp =~ s/<.*?>//sg;
            print "Stealing from: " . $tmp;
            $mech->form_name(0);
            $mech->select("Opp", $tmp);
            $mech->click_button('value' => 'Steal Stats or Items');
            $a = $mech->content();
            $a =~ m/(sleepers.*This)/s;
            $b = $1;
            $b =~ s/<.*?>//sg;
            $b =~ s/sleepers//sg;
            $b =~ s/This//sg;
            print $b;
    } else {$stealtime = time; $stealtime = $stealtime + 2000; print "Freeplay not detected, stealing cancelled...\n";}
}
```

I'm no expert when it comes to scripting, and any insight on how I might correct this problem or override Mechanize timeouts would be much appreciated .

Comment: Start by actually pointing out which lines 299 and 97 are in your Perl code.

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;`, fix the large amount of errors and warnings that you no doubt will get, then repost your question -- if your problem remains. Most of the errors will no doubt be regarding using explicit package name, which is solved by declaring variables with `my $foo` in the block they are used. Also, do not use `$a` and `$b` as they are reserved for use with the `sort` function.

Comment: 299 is the first block, $mech->reload() line, in the #REPEAT section like I wrote in my original post . 

99 is the first $mech->get("http://www.lordsoflords.com/m3/steal.php"); from the second block of code

Comment: I didnt write it originally I'm only trying to make it work for me, the whole script has use strict and use warnings in it

Comment: Then the script no doubt has all its variables declared at the top. Glancing at the code, I would say if it works at all, its mostly out of old habit or pure luck. In order to know why your post/get fails, you would need to check what the post/get looks like. I assume you have read the documentation for the Mechanize module?

Answer (score 1):

Catch the exceptions with [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try%3a%3aTiny) or something, wait a bit (with [exponential back-off](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=exponential+back-off)), then resend the request. It is common Internet courtesy to hard-code an upper limit for retries so you do not end up hammering the server.

Comment: I went to the website before, and I do recall reading something about "reasons for getting logged out" is performing requests faster than once per second.

Comment: Yes you're correct, however this script previously functioned well inside of the servers built in request cap. There is a loopwait variable set to the shell script that adjusts the wait time for the reloads

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that I cannot locate the PXPerl version that was originally shipped with the script ? I've self compiled a long list of libs and modules from my package manager but is it possible I'm missing something to handle this kind of thing that may have been present ? We're talking like an 8 year old version of PXPerl this was written with originally.